# How to skip Fluent validation static function during unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am using xunit with Moq and testing other functionality in one function but i always get an exception from Fluent Validation extension methods which I can not bypass.

This is original code

```
    public class AdService : IAdService
{
    private readonly IValidator<AdToSearchDto> _adToSearchDtoValidator;
    public AdService(IValidator<AdToSearchDto> addToSearchDtoValidator)
    {
        _adToSearchDtoValidator = addToSearchDtoValidator
    }

    public async Task<AdsToReturnDto> GetAdsAsync(AdToSearchDto searchDto)
    {
         _adToSearchDtoValidator.ValidateAndThrow(searchDto); // This line always throw exception

          return await _adRepository.GetUserAdsAsync(searchDto, userId, user?.Country);            
    }

}
```

Unit test class

```
 [Fact]
public async Task Ads_Can_Searched_By_UserId()
{
    var validator = new Mock<IValidator<AdToSearchDto>>();

    var adService = new AdService(validator.Object);

    var adService = new AdService(validator.Object );

    var ads = DataGenerator.CreateAds(2);
    ads[0].UserId = searchingUserId;
    ads[1].UserId = anotherUserId;

    await adRepository.CreateAdAsync(ads[0]);
    await adRepository.CreateAdAsync(ads[1]);

    var result = await adService.GetAdsAsync( adToSearchDto, Guid.Empty ) ;

    result.Ads.Count.Should().Be(1);
    result.Ads.FirstOrDefault()?.UserId.Should().Be(searchingUserId.ToString());

}
```

I cant bypass

> ValidateAndThrow

as this is extension method.

Is there any way to bypass ValidateAndThrow method in unit test **?**

Edited:

Error i am getting

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at FluentValidation.DefaultValidatorExtensions.ValidateAndThrow[T](IValidator`1 validator, T instance, String ruleSet) in C:\Projects\FluentValidation\src\FluentValidation\DefaultValidatorExtensions.cs:line 943
   at Market.Business.Ad.AdService.GetAdsAsync(AdToSearchDto searchDto, Guid userId) in C:\Users\Shahid Abdullah\Projects\MyStuff.IdentityServer\src\Market\Market.Business\Ad\AdService.cs:line 129
   at Market.Test.Ad.AdTests.Ads_Can_Searched_By_UserId() in C:\Users\Shahid Abdullah\Projects\MyStuff.IdentityServer\src\Market\Market.Test\Ad\AdTests.cs:line 100
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Exception in source code

```
public static void ValidateAndThrow<T>(
      this IValidator<T> validator,
      T instance,
      string ruleSet = null)
    {
      ValidationResult validationResult = validator.Validate<T>(instance, (IValidatorSelector) null, ruleSet);
      if (!validationResult.IsValid) // this line throws exception as validationResult is null
        throw new ValidationException((IEnumerable<ValidationFailure>) validationResult.Errors);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error

Comment: @Nkosi I have added error in original question.

Comment: Include the full test and the method under test

Comment: From stack trace It does look like an extension method is being called. Will need to check source code to see what that expects when invomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Performs validation and then throws an exception if validation fails.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="validator">The validator this method is extending.</param>
    /// <param name="instance">The instance of the type we are validating.</param>
    /// <param name="ruleSet">Optional: a ruleset when need to validate against.</param>
    public static void ValidateAndThrow<T>(this IValidator<T> validator, T instance, string ruleSet = null) {
        var result = validator.Validate(instance, ruleSet: ruleSet);

        if (!result.IsValid) {
            throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);
        }
    }
```

[Source](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation/DefaultValidatorExtensions.cs#L946)

`ValidateAndThrow` expects a result to be return from the validator when invoked.

Because there is no result from the mock

```
if (!result.IsValid) {...
```

throws a null reference exception.

Setup the mock to behave as expected when the extension method is invoked while exercising the test

```
[Fact]
public async Task Ads_Can_Searched_By_UserId() {
    //Arrange
    var validator = new Mock<IValidator<AdToSearchDto>>();

    var validResult = new ValidationResult();
    validator
        .Setup(_ => _.Validate(It.IsAny<ValidationContext>())
        .Returns(validResult);

    var adService = new AdService(validator.Object);

    //...
}
```